# How fast can people dig in rock using primitive methods?

Tags: geology, history

Considering the fire setting method (where you light a fire in front of the rock, then pour water onto the fire and rock) and digging purely with unpowered hand tools, how long would it take to dig through a cubic meter of soft, medium, and hard rock? Consider the case where the digger stands right in front of a featureless rock wall.

Comment: I wish there was a "#minecraft" tag here

Comment: What is the intended meaning of the phrases "soft rock", "medium rock" and "hard rock"? Give specific examples of such rocks. What are "primitive tools"? For example, are steel tools allowed? By a cubic metre, you mean a cube with a one metre side, or is it acceptable to get that volume of rock chips by scraping off one centimeter of rock from an area of one hundred square metres? How many rock diggers are there?

Comment: This may be answered better on HistorySE - there are bound to be records of mines including workforce and length of time to extend mineshafts - but more detail (what AlexP has asked for) and evidence of prior research are required.

Comment: In *Hell on Wheels* (fiction, I know), one of the railroadmen complained that (with a very large crew) he was doing "12 a day, inches that is, not miles". It's impossible to mine out a cubic meter, because you need the tunnel to be big enough to work in, if it is small then only one person at a time can be at the head further limiting speed.

Answer (score 10):

There is an interesting Jstor paper [The Use of Fire in Prehistoric and Ancient Mining : Firesetting](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41496587?seq=1) that goes into great detail about the pluses and minuses of firesetting. It has sketches of how the fires were positioned underground etc. It includes mention of an experiment someone did in a mine.
[image: table from article]

My guess is this was medium to hard, hardness rock, soft rock can be dug with other methods, and there are prehistoric mines for chert nodules in chalk, or mines for red ochre, that are quite old.

[Roman tunnels](https://www.worldhistory.org/article/882/roman-tunnels/)

> When the rock was hard, Romans employed a technique called fire-quenching which consisted of heating the rock with fire, and then suddenly cooling it with cold water so that it would crack. Progress through hard rock could be very slow and it was not uncommon for tunnels to take years if not decades to be built. Construction marks left on a Roman tunnel in Bologna shows us that the rate of advance through solid rock was 30 cm (12 inches) per day. In constrast, the rate of advance of the Claudius tunnel can be calculated at 1.4 m (55 inches) per day.

Apparently the Inca, would also drill then put flammable materials in the hole to weaken the rock.

So I think you question depends a lot on the details, but pretty interesting to consider how long or big some of the tunnels, mines and aqueducts were.

Edit: Typical aqueduct was about 1.5 x 0.7 meters or about 1 meter squares in area. So using the Roman numbers above, about 1.4 cubic meters per day, for the softer volcanic rock, and about 1/3 a cubic meter a day for the harder rock.

Comment: Looks like a good source.  May be worth updating your answer to add a final calculation of volume per unit time based on the cross section of the Roman tunnels and/or extrapolating from the figures in the table and using an average density of likely rock types (2.5 kg/l?)

Comment: Note that the period in the numbers indicates thousands; it's not a decimal mark.